# How to interpret "well-worn"?

Tags: word-usage, interpretation

When talking about conditions of collectibles or other stuff, I have read some days ago "well-worn" and I'm not sure how to interpret it. I actually see 2 different ways to interpret it, which would mean even quite the opposite of each other.

One way I see would be:

It was worn well, so when it was used, and was handled carefully(well) with.
So this would mean the condition of the item is still fine.

Or the other way:

Well as an expression for frequency, so it means it has bean worn a lot, what would lead to an condition with a lot of signs of wear and tear.

So what's the way it should be interpreted?
And what are the indications that (if so) exclude the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well-worn** has the meaning of **often used**, **not new**, and in the extreme **threadbare**.

Clothing which is **new** has a certain feeling of **crispness** and **stiffness**. After it has been **broken in**, greets tend to have a different **more comfortable** feel about them and **hang** better on the wearer.

After clothes have been **worn for a time**, certain discolourations may appear in **stress points**, for example in the **elbows or knees**, or possibly some **fraying** in the button holes, and these would make the garment considered to be **well-worn**.

> The owner has **worn** the garment **well** *(often)*.

This may occur through routine usage over some **passage of time**, or because it is a **favourite** of the owner and worn fairly often, or both.

**Well-worn** does not have the meaning of being worn in an **attractive way** in the same way that **well-spoken** means a person is **eloquent**.  Phrasing used to convey that idea might be

> It's you
>   It suits you
>   It becomes you
>   You look good in that

meaning *something* was **worn** **well** (verb + adverb) but not necessarily **well-worn**(adjective)

> He **wore** that tuxedo very **well**
>   He **wore** that uniform **well**

Could be said about the handsome **appearance of the wearer**, however neither garment would probably be called **well-worn**

> The actor **wore** the **well-worn** tweed jacket very **well** as a professor.

Comment: Well I actually still don't understand how it excludes the other way. But thats probably a problem on my site and not in your explanation. Anyway, I'll just wait a little bit more before accepting an answer. Maybe some one else can get me on to it :P +1 anyway. Nice explanation.

Comment: @Zaibis Do you have a quote or passage for **the other way**?

Comment: The Point is I don't have a passage for any way, since I wrote this OP as I wasn't able to make the difference(if there is one). So I can't say even if I had oen. But what I'm asking for is: I presented 2 ways **I** would have understood it. And I'm asking for what is the correct one and why you couldn't understand it in the opposite way I presented it. I'm not saying your explanation for this is unsatisfying. I just say I don't get it what you explain regarding the second part.

Comment: There is an expression: **well-spoken** which means **eloquent** or that a person **spoke well**. **Well-worn** is not the same way, it does not mean **worn well** meaning an attractive/fashionable way. I'm guessing your confusion is that **well-worn** (worn a lot) sounds like **worn well** (worn in a good way). They have two totally different meanings (as you point out) but **worn well** would not be written **well-worn**. Does that help?

Comment: Kind of helps. What I'm asking now for is, whats the reason (like a rule or so) that well-worn wouldn't be understood as worn well? If it is just as it is, because it is. Than I'm fine with it. But I'm just waiting a bit as maybe some one can say something to it. If not, I'll accept your answer as it is right now :)

Comment: It's good of you to wait.  **Well-worn** only has the more **tattered** meaning [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=well-worn+definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=j3iTVpmEBOOq8weF95nACw). I also added the constructs in my answer since it may help others: **well-worn** is an adjective, **worn well** is verb+adverb. If I may ask: what is you native language?  There's a lot that native speakers take for granted.

Comment: My native language is german. And my confusion probably comes from the diferent meanings one can translate to in german and the ways we can use the translations here.